# Magento 2 Google Merchant center product feed export

Tags: magento2

I am using Amasty Product Feed for Magento 2 Module to manage the online products appears on google

Google Merchant Center lets manage how our in-store and online product inventory appears on Google.

I am having trouble determining the shipping cost per product.
Can anybody please guide me if it's an optional attribute if yes then nothing to check?
If not then how to pass the shipping cost product-wise.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the shipping settings in Merchant Center to manually configure account-level shipping services. If you prefer to set your shipping cost and time for each product, use the shipping [shipping] attribute instead.

You can read more here: https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6069284?hl=en

Hope it can help you.